# Change color in ionic.app.scss

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to change the color positive in my ionic.app.scss file like here is my file

```
$positive:#106CA4 !default;

// The path for our ionicons font files, relative to the built CSS in www/css
$ionicons-font-path: "../lib/ionic/fonts" !default;

// Include all of Ionic
@import "www/lib/ionic/scss/ionic";
```

But the color is not overriden, why does it not change?

Comment: Did the sass compile? Do you have `ionic serve` running?

Answer (score 0):

I usually overridden ionic's pre-defined classes like `positive` or `balanced` according to design other than overridden its variables. But if you really want do that, as [the official doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#colors) says, you can override them within **_variables.scss** file.

> To customize the colors you can simply override those coming from the ionic.css CSS file. Additionally, since Ionic is built using Sass, for more power and flexibility you could also modify and extend the color variables within the _variables.scss file.